# JSONDecodeError when using airflow GoogleBaseHook in python

Tags: python, airflow, credentials

I followed this [official document](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html) to run airflow in docker. In my local airflow webserver (localhost:8080), I create a Google Cloud connection by pasting my google credential.json in `Keyfile JSON` and add 2 scopes (shown in the picture below)

[airflow connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeZeL.png)

my credential looks like:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxxx-tech",
  "private_key_id": "xxxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nXXXXX=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "xxx@tech.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "10xxxx17",
  "auth_uri": "https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3xxxxx= ",
  "token_uri": "https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3xxxxx ",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3xxxxxx= ",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3xxxxxx= "
}
```

I want to use airflow's hook to get this credential for reading data in Google Sheet.
But in my python code, I tried:

```py
from airflow.providers.google.common.hooks.base_google import GoogleBaseHook
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

gcp_hook = GoogleBaseHook(gcp_conn_id="spx-service-account")
creds = gcp_hook._get_credentials()
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds, cache_discovery=False)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId="1yN3atY6NG7PfY8yNcNAiVqURra8WtQJWCKXc-ccymk0", range="Sheet1!A1:B4").execute()['values']
```

But executing this python in terminal shows `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0dcp.png)

I don't know why it shows JSONDecodeError. I also tried the following code. Printing `cred_dict` in terminal shows the exact same content as my credential.json

```py
gcp_hook = GoogleBaseHook(gcp_conn_id="spx-service-account")
cred_dict = json.loads(gcp_hook._get_field('keyfile_dict'))
```

From the test above, I guess it may not be a json decode issue, but I still cannot use GoogleBaseHook in my python code. I wonder how can I set airflow connection in the right way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using puckel/airflow docker image?

Comment: I followed this [document](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html), so I guess it is `apache/airflow` (?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, it ends up to be something wrong with my credential.json. I have no idea why those `token_uri` is encoded when I downloaded it from my Gmail (tech team sent it to us via email) and opened it with my windows laptop. If your credential is correct, the code below should work:

```
from airflow.providers.google.common.hooks.base_google import GoogleBaseHook
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

gcp_hook = GoogleBaseHook(gcp_conn_id="spx-service-account")
creds = gcp_hook._get_credentials()
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds, cache_discovery=False)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId="1yN3atY6NG7PfY8yNcNAiVqURra8WtQJWCKXc-ccymk0", range="Sheet1!A1:B4").execute()['values']
```